# Uniqueness of infinite direct sum decomposition

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

A module $M$ over a ring $R$ is called *semisimple* if it admits a direct sum decomposition into simple modules. If $M$ admits a *finite* decomposition $M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n S_i$ into simple $R$-modules $S_i$, then this decomposition is unique up to isomorphism and permutation of the factors because from such a decomposition one can cook up a composition series and then use the Jordan–Hölder theorem.

I would like to know: are *infinite* decompositions unique as well?

E.g. if $R$ is semisimple, then *all* $R$-modules are semisimple. Do they decompose uniquely?

Comment: What's unique is the decomposition is into isotypic summands. The decomposition into simple summands is only unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, see [Decomposition of a module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_a_module) — this is Azumaya theorem.

Comment: A reference is T-Y. Lam. “Lectures on modules and rings”. Graduate Texts in Math. 189. SpringerVerlag, New York, 1999.

Comment: @abx: You sure? This is about the Krull-Schmidt theorem which I thought only applies to finite direct sum decompositions!?

Comment: @YCor: Sorry, could you elaborate a bit more? I'm not sure I got this.

Comment: In a semisimple module $M$, an isotypic component $N$ is a submodule such that all its simple submodules are isomorphic, and isomorphic to no simple submodule of $M/N$. Then every semisimple module is direct sum of its isotypic components, and every decomposition of $M$ into direct sum of simple module is a refinement of the isotypic decomposition. Each isotypic component is isomorphic direct powers $S^{(\alpha)}$ of some simple module $S$, uniquely determined up to isomorphism, and the power (the cardinal $\alpha$), multiplicity of $S$, is uniquely defined.

Comment: I am sure, please read the Wikipedia article I linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. A semisimple module $M$ is *canonically* isomorphic to

$$M \cong \bigoplus_i \text{Hom}_R(S_i, M) \otimes_{\text{End}(S_i)} S_i$$

where $\text{Hom}_R(S_i, M)$ is what you might call the multiplicity space of the simple module $S_i$. It is naturally a module over the division ring $\text{End}(S_i)$, and from this expression it follows that the multiplicity of $S_i$ in any direct sum decomposition of $M$ into simples must be $\dim_{\text{End}(S_i)} \text{Hom}_R(S_i, M)$. (For this we need to know that $\text{Hom}_R(S_i, -)$ preserves infinite coproducts, but this follows from the fact that simple modules are cyclic and so in particular finitely generated.)